# codeigniter active records join with using?

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, activerecord

I am wanting to write this query:

```
SELECT u.userId, uil.interestId, url.regionId FROM users u 
  JOIN userInterestLink uil USING (userId)
  JOIN userRegionLink url USING (userId)
  JOIN dealInterestLink dil USING (interestId)
  JOIN dealRegionLink drl USING (regionId, dealId)
WHERE dealId = 1
```

using the code igniter active records class, however I have no ideda how to do the `JOIN ... USING`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no built-in support for `JOIN ... USING` in the active record class. Your best bet would probably change the `join()` function to be like this (the file is `system/database/DB_active_rec.php` in case you don't know)

```
public function join($table, $cond, $type = '')
{
    if ($type != '')
    {
        $type = strtoupper(trim($type));

        if ( ! in_array($type, array('LEFT', 'RIGHT', 'OUTER', 'INNER', 'LEFT OUTER', 'RIGHT OUTER')))
        {
            $type = '';
        }
        else
        {
            $type .= ' ';
        }
    }

    // Extract any aliases that might exist.  We use this information
    // in the _protect_identifiers to know whether to add a table prefix
    $this->_track_aliases($table);

    // Strip apart the condition and protect the identifiers
    if (preg_match('/([\w\.]+)([\W\s]+)(.+)/', $cond, $match))
    {
        $match[1] = $this->_protect_identifiers($match[1]);
        $match[3] = $this->_protect_identifiers($match[3]);

        $cond = $match[1].$match[2].$match[3];
    }

    // Assemble the JOIN statement
    $type.'JOIN '.$this->_protect_identifiers($table, TRUE, NULL, FALSE);

    $using_match = preg_match('/using[ (]/i', $cond);

    if ($using_match)
    {
        $join .= $cond;
    }
    else
    {
        $join .= ' ON '.$cond;
    }

    $this->ar_join[] = $join;
    if ($this->ar_caching === TRUE)
    {
        $this->ar_cache_join[] = $join;
        $this->ar_cache_exists[] = 'join';
    }

    return $this;
}
```

So then, you can simply use this in your code `join('table', 'USING ("something")')`

Although, you might want to extend the class instead of modifying it so that you won't need to do same thing over and over again when you upgrade your CI. 
Have a look at this [article](http://codeigniter.com/wiki/Extending_Database_Drivers) or [this one](http://robotslacker.com/2011/05/extending-codeigniters-active-record-class/) (or search google) if you want to do so instead.

Or if you don't want to go all those troubles, you can write a simple helper function that can do the same thing.

```
<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

function join_using($table, $key) 
{
    $CI = get_instance();
    $join = 'JOIN '. $table .' USING (`'. $key .'`)';
    return $CI->db->ar_join[] = $join;
}
```

Later on, just load the helper and call the function like this `join_using('table', 'key')`. It will then produce the same result as you would with the original `join()` except this one will give you `USING` instead of `ON` condition.

For example:

```
// $something1 and $something2 will produce the same result.
$something1 = $this->db->join('join_table', 'join_table.id = table.id')->get('table')->result();
print_r($something1);
join_using('join_table', 'id');
$something2 = $this->db->get('table')->result();
print_r($something2);
```