# CodeIgniter Active Record use "USING" in query

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am trying to replicate the following query using Active Record in CodeIgniter but I can't find where in the documentation or searching how you use `USING` in a query.

```
SELECT * 
FROM categories C
LEFT OUTER JOIN motorcycle_brands MB
USING ( CatID ) 
LEFT OUTER JOIN powersport_categories PS
USING ( CatID ) 
WHERE C.CatID = :uniqueID
```

This is what I have now:

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('categories C');
$this->db->join('motorcycle_brands MB', 'CatID', 'left outer');
$this->db->join('powersport_categories PS', 'CatID', 'left outer');
$this->db->where('C.CatID =', $this->option_id);
$suboptions = $this->db->get();
```

I have tried changing

```
$this->db->join('motorcycle_brands MB', 'USING (CatID)', 'left outer');
$this->db->join('powersport_categories PS', 'USING (CatID)', 'left outer');
```

Comment: Are you getting any error on your code which you mentioned below `This is what I have now:`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no built-in support for JOIN using USING in the active record class. The best that you can do is change the join() function in "system/database/DB_active_rec.php" this file.

Please refer this question for the complete reference.
[codeigniter active records join with using?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7378420/codeigniter-active-records-join-with-using)

Answer (score 0):

The `USING` clause is used if several columns share the same name but you don’t want to join using all of these common columns. The columns listed in the USING clause can’t have any qualifiers in the statement, including the WHERE clause:

The `ON` clause is used to join tables where the column names don’t match in both tables. The join conditions are removed from the filter conditions in the WHERE clause:

So your code should be,

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('categories C');
$this->db->join('motorcycle_brands MB', 'MB.CatID = C.Id', 'left outer');
$this->db->join('powersport_categories PS', 'C.Id = PS.CatID ', 'left outer');
$this->db->where('C.CatID =', $this->option_id);
$suboptions = $this->db->get();
```

Comment: This gives me an error but I figured it out since I posted this question but now my issue is that I have `SubID` and `SubName` in both `motorcycle_brands` and `powersport_categories` so it is returning null values for `motorcycle_brands` but returning all rows in `powersport_categories` I need to figure out what to do next to fix this

Comment: Error because of columns names. I just posted answer with dummy column names. hope you can change column names as you have in table.